# How to sort the row of record and update dynamically in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Clarification on SQL query syntax : we have an `Employee` table which has two columns `Emp Id` and `EmpName` and its values looks like this:

```
100, a
200, b
300, c
```

I have to update the `EmpName` for 100 with "Joe", 200 with "John", 300 with "Sam". These same 3 names then need to repeat in order for the rest of the table.

How to pick EmpId in ascending order sequence and update the EmpName accordingly?

Comment: The logic is unclear.   If the next `Emp ID` was 500 what would you want the `EmpName` to be?   "Test4" or "Test5"?

Comment: `Update employee set EmpName = "Test" & EmpID/100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cteRowNums AS (
    SELECT EmpId,
           EmpName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpId) AS RowNum
        FROM Employee
)
UPDATE cteRowNums
    SET EmpName = CASE WHEN RowNum % 3 = 1 THEN 'Joe'
                       WHEN RowNum % 3 = 2 THEN 'John'
                       WHEN RowNum % 3 = 0 THEN 'Sam'
                  END;
```

Comment: Seeing your solution, I now understand the question.  +1

Comment: Hello @ Joe, this is very helpful.. however update the EmpName has to be custom.. for example .. Row 1 might be Joe, Row 2 might be John, Row 3 might be Mike ..  - How to update the EmpName .. on passing these 3 values .. in the sequence order

Comment: @goofyui I do not understand your expected outcome then.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli It's not really deja vue, anyway the OP question seems now not clear.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, right now.. you are forcing the empname to be as Test1, Test2, Test3 ..  Whatever i gave was a sample set of data. However in reality, we need to update 3 hard coded names  in the asc sequential order of the id column

Comment: @goofyui Then you just want to append a number to the existing EmpName?

Comment: @goofyui So you need to update you question with a better sample and expected results, as _formatted text_.

Comment: I do not want to append any number. Please forgive my sample data which i posted. In reality, we will be updating 3 actual names such as Joe, John , Sam in the sequential order

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add a row_num column 
after that update using ROW_NUMBER()
something like

```
 Alter table emp1 add row_num varchar(10)

    with cte as (
 select id,name,row_num,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [id]) as rn
 from emp1
 )
 update cte set row_num = 'Test'+ convert(varchar,rn)
```

row_number this will create a ordered column regarding [Emp Id].
and run update statement to get desired result.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Being new does not give protection against down votes. Trust me, it's not always easy, but don't take them personally. In fact, they can be a valuable way for new users to learn and improve. (And I am not downvoting you). https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down